# Jump to today's date + offset 10 rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

New to scripting. Have a planner in Google sheets which is displayed on a monitor in the office. 
I have a script to make it jump to today's date on open (found here). The planner is organized with 1st of January on top, 31st of December bottom.

I want to make the sheet open to today's date +10 (row), like an offset if possible.

Script:

```
function onOpen() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getRange("B:B");
 var values = range.getValues();  
 var day = 24*3600*1000;  
 var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day);  
 var ssdate; 
 for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
   try {
     ssdate = values[i][0].getTime()/day;
   }
   catch(e) {
   }
   if (ssdate && Math.floor(ssdate) == today) {
     sheet.setActiveRange(range.offset(i,0,1,1));
     break;
   }    
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you were looking for was:

```
sheet.setActiveRange(range.offset(i+10,0,1,1));
```

Answer (score 0):

try: `sheet.setActiveRange(range.offset(i,10,1,1))`

or: `sheet.setActiveRange(range.offset(i,0,11,1))`

or: `sheet.setActiveRange(range.offset(i,0,1,11))`

Comment: Thank you. It seems these alternatives refer to markings in the spreadsheet. Alt. 3 marks the entire row, but the pages only jumps down to today's date.